# Concept behind converting Base16 to Base64

Tags: base64, hex

I understand how to read decimal, binary, hex and base64; that is I can manually convert numbers/counts expressed as each of those bases to expressions in the other bases.

I'm doing the matasano crypto challenges and the very first assignment got me thinking (https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/1).

The approaches to this problem that I found convert the hexstring to bytes (binary) and then the bytes to base64. Which I understand. Or so I thought. Could I simply concatenate these bytes and say I have the binarystring expression of the same number?

I noticed they basically read the hexstring 2 hexcharacters at a time (because 2 hexcharacters is one byte at most). This results in a binarystring where each binarycharacter(bit) is "aligned" with the hexcharacter(s) it came from.

Does this mean I can just convert this binarystring to decimal and it will be same "number" that the hexstring represents?

Could a similar character-by-character scheme be done to convert to base64? How many hexcharacters per base64character?

Comment: You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: @Flimzy yes. sorry about that, did not mean to

Answer (score 0):

@Flimzy shared this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and the way it answered my question is realizing two things:

- base16 is an octet based encoding
- base64 is a sextet based encoding